# redirect all down.php?name=iptools.online extensions to .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to automatically redirect `down.php?name=NAME` on the main page of the site.

For example:

```
http://example.com/down.php?name=iptools.online
```

to

```
http://example.com/iptools.online
```

I tried with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /down.php?name=$1 [L]
```

It works, but when using the old URL, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Your example URL does not include the `.html` (mentioned in the title and used in your current directive) - so, I assume this must be a typo and the `.html` extension is required?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *before* your existing rewrite:

```
# Redirect "/down.php?name=value" to "/value"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^down\.php$ /%1.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the preceding *CondPattern* that captures the value of the `name` URL parameter.

The `QSD` flag is required to discard the original query string from the request.

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is required to prevent a redirect loop.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect, before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect in order to avoid caching issues.

> ...on the main page of the site.

Note that you must have already updated all your internal links to point to the desired URL. The redirect above is not to redirect internal links, but to redirect search engine crawlers and 3rd party inbound links to the old URLs in order preserve SEO.

Comment: Hi,this works for redirect, but the page does not show, it shows my site homepage.

Comment: You placed this code just before your existing rewrite? What URL are you requesting?